# How to dynamically add elements at index to Python list?

Tags: python, list

Given some Python list,

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

for some of its characters contained in another list, e.g.

```
list2 = ['a', 'd', 'e']
```

I need to add a character `{char}1` to the index right before the original character in `list1`, such that the updated `list1` looks like this:

```
list1 = ['a1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd', 'e1', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

My initial idea was to store the indices of original elements in a dictionary, and then `insert` new ones to `[i-1]` in `list1`,
`in range (1, len(list1)+1)`. However, I then realised that this would only work for the first element, because the list would then grow and the indices would shift, so I would get wrong results.

Is there an efficient way to do it using `insert`?

Comment: How big are the lists?

Comment: What happens if the item _isn't_ in `list1`? What about if `{char}1` is already in `list1`?

Comment: @roganjosh why is this important?

Comment: @Axe319 just assume these edge cases do not need to be covered at the moment.

Comment: @JJKam because time complexity will get the better of you if you don't have something efficient. You can probably live with a simple solution for small lists, but it'll blow up on larger ones

Comment: @roganjosh well then I guess a good solution would be size-agnostic

Comment: I also agree that this would be the ideal solution, but it's one hell of a challenge. I'll have a think. All of the solutions so far are doing multiple passes at the list

Comment: I don't think using insert is going to be good, inserting is going to make the solution O(n*m) in contrast creating the list from scratch is O(n + m) using a set

Comment: @DaniMesejo it'd be useful to add this complexity explanation to your answer!

Comment: I suspect that the solution by @DaniMesejo is the best way here. No choice but to build the list back up from scratch

Comment: Are the input lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @ThePhoton  it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
list2 = ['a', 'd', 'e']

result = []
for e in list1:
    if e in list2:
        result.extend([f"{e}1", e])
    else:
        result.append(e)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['a1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd', 'e1', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

If `list2` is large consider transforming it to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Like below:

```
result = []
set2 = set(list2)
for char in list1:
    if char in set2:
        result.extend([f"{char}1", char])
    else:
        result.append(char)
```

The second solution is *O(n + m)* expected, where *n* and *m* are the size of `list1` and `list2`.

`append` is `O(1)` (this means the cost of the operation is constant), `extend` is a *repeated* `append` (and in the context of the question is also constant). From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable.
> Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.

**Note:** Using `insert` is going to make the approach *O(n * m)*, since inserting in a list has a linear complexity (see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)). The linear complexity comes from the fact that the list has to *shift* the elements.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach with `insert`:

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
list2 = ['a', 'd', 'e'] 


for e in list2:
    list1.insert(list1.index(e), f'{e}1')

list1
>>> ['a1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd', 'e1', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
list2 = ['a', 'd', 'e']

list1 = [*chain.from_iterable((i,[i+'1',i])[i in list2] for i in list1)]

# ['a1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd', 'e1', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Or `join` and `split`:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
list2 = ['a', 'd', 'e']

list1 = ' '.join([(i,' '.join([i+'1',i]))[i in list2] for i in list1]).split()

# ['a1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd', 'e1', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```